# How do we convert UUID to date in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am very new to Perl language. How to convert the `UUID` to date format `2011-04-22` ?

For example, I have UUID like this

`118ffe80-466b-11e1-b5a5-5732cf729524`.

How to convert this to date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module [UUID::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/UUID::Tiny) has a method called time_of_UUID() that might help:

**time_of_UUID()**

```
This function accepts UUIDs and UUID strings. 
Returns the time as a   floating point value, so use int() 
to get a time() compatible value.

Returns undef if the UUID is not version 1.

my $uuid_time = time_of_UUID($uuid);
```

The Timestamp section of [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1.4) can also complement the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) article about UUID.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this javascript API can help you to convert the UUID to date format,

this API convert UUID v1 to sec from 1970-01-01

**[UUID_to_Date](https://github.com/xehrad/UUID_to_Date)**

---

---

**all of you need:**

```
    get_time_int = function (uuid_str) {
        var uuid_arr = uuid_str.split( '-' ),
            time_str = [
                uuid_arr[ 2 ].substring( 1 ),
                uuid_arr[ 1 ],
                uuid_arr[ 0 ]
            ].join( '' );
        return parseInt( time_str, 16 );
    };

    get_date_obj = function (uuid_str) {
        var int_time = this.get_time_int( uuid_str ) - 122192928000000000,
            int_millisec = Math.floor( int_time / 10000 );
        return new Date( int_millisec );
    };
```

---

---

## Example:

```
    var date_obj = get_date_obj(  '8bf1aeb8-6b5b-11e4-95c0-001dba68c1f2' );
    date_obj.toLocaleString( );// '11/13/2014, 9:06:06 PM'
```

Comment: Javascript is simple language and this simple code can help to writing API for every language.