# How can i convert Localdatetime to UUID and back to datetime

Tags: java, uuid

I would like to convert LocalDateTime "2021-10-07T21:45:14" to UUID.
And then use this UUID.timestamp to use later.

I try to use

`UUIDGen.getTimeUUID( LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-10-07T21:45:14" ).getLong( ChronoField.MILLI_OF_DAY ) )`

which generates
6a495100-1e88-11b2-b064-0fb9cd38af13, which is not correct date time "1970-01-01 21:45:14.000000.0 UTC"

Comment: Milli of day is the number of millis that happened in the day so far--note how the time is correct.

Comment: FYI, UUID was never designed to be a date-time storage type. Some versions of UUID have a date-time embedded, and some do not.

Comment: Milli of day always returns a unique number that you can use a unique ID. You will then easily revert it back to the corresponding date.

Comment: @HarryCoder how can i do it?  as you see 6a495100-1e88-11b2-b064-0fb9cd38af13,] is revert back to date time "1970-01-01 21:45:14.000000.0 UTC" which is not correct

Comment: Try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179428/how-do-i-extract-a-date-from-a-uuid-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: convert `LocalDateTime` to `Instant` and then to milliseconds

```java
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-10-07T21:45:14");
UUIDGen.getTimeUUID(datetime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli());
```

Option 2: convert `Instant` to milliseconds

```java
UUIDGen.getTimeUUID(Instant.parse("2021-10-07T21:45:14Z").toEpochMilli()); // Z = UTC
```